# Send general MongoDB query in HTTP request

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need to send the following example MongoDB query from a React.JS frontend app to a backend Node.js API via URL request params:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId('507f1f77bcf86cd799439011'),
  name: {
    $in: ['foo', 'bar']
  }
}
```

However, `ObjectId` is a function and cannot be serialized to JSON. So, I tried this BSON form as proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486720/6039697:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"
  },
  "name": {
    "$in": ["foo", "bar"]
  }
}
```

But MongoDB show this error

```
{
    "message" : "unknown operator: $oid",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : NumberInt(2),
    "codeName" : "BadValue",
    "name" : "MongoError"
}
```

I Know I could check for `_id`s and parse in the API, but I would like to make this transparent and automatic. Does anyone have an idea on how can I get this working?

Comment: It sounds like you want to to backend stuff in the frontend. Are you using mongoose? What you should do is issue a `GET` on something like `myapi.com/whatever/507f1f77bcf86cd799439011`. On you backend, you can simply get that id from the parameters object and pass it to mongoose.

Comment: @ffritz yeah, I wanto to make queries in general from the frontend. I'm using mongoose. The route id you propose are already in use for patch/delete request mappings, but I need to make queries with other fields other than _id, so, do it in route ids will not work

Comment: I'll insert the general queries part in question to make it more clear

Comment: It sounds like you almost want a "catch all" route which freely parses mongoDB queries from your frontend. That is a very bad idea, as it opens very critical attack vectors.

Comment: Yes! You are totally right. But I think if I encrypt this query it will be more safe to attacks. What do you think?

Comment: Well it doesn't matter if you encrypt it or not, you still have a route open (presumably to the whole internet), which accepts any kind of mongoDB query and sends it to your DB. That means any authenticated client could send harmful commands directly to your DB. You have to realize that you would accept any kind of query, not just the specific one in your question. Don't implement it this way. Always write mongoDB queries on the server.

Comment: The big problem is that I have various CRUD controllers with many filters, and implement those filters logic in the backend will be very painful/tedious. Do you know a strategy/pattern to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: No sorry, I don't. I also don't see how it would be so much more work to write them in the backend, because you would have to write them in the frontend anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question. This package solved my problem https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson

```
const { EJSON } = require('bson');

const mongoDBQuery = EJSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"
  },
  "name": {
    "$in": ["foo", "bar"]
  }
}), { relaxed: true });

console.log(mongoDBQuery);
```